# How can I get maven to run mySQL plug at "mvn test"

Tags: java, mysql, maven

How can I get maven to run the following plug-in each time I run "mvn test".

I dont want to issue "mvn sql:execute" everytime I want this to run

```
<plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>sql-maven-plugin</artifactId>

                        <!-- JDBC Driver -->
                        <dependencies>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                                <version>5.0.5</version>
                            </dependency>
                        </dependencies>

                        <configuration>
                            <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
                            <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jboss</url>
                            <username>xxx</username>
                            <password>xxxx</password>
                            <autocommit>true</autocommit>
                            <onError>continue</onError>
                            <srcFiles>
                                <srcFile>src/test/sql/removeuser.sql</srcFile>
                            </srcFiles>
                        </configuration>

                    </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

I created [`jcabi-mysql-maven-plugin`](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-mysql-maven-plugin/usage.html) exactly fo this purpose. It starts MySQL server at `pre-integration-test` phase and shuts it down at `post-integration-test` phase.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind your goal(sql:execute) to the test phase by adding the following inside the plugin tag:

```
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>execute-sql</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>execute</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
```

Comment: I would suggest to put it into the *process-test-resources* phase to be sure it's executed before the tests. In this it might not 100% sure to be executed before the tests.